# Show $N_G(N_G(P))=N_G(P)$ when $P$ is a Sylow $p$-group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

I am looking at the following exercise:

> Let $P$ be a $p$-Sylow subgroup of $G$ then $N_G(N_G(P))=N_G(P)$.

When $P\in \text{Syl}_p(G)$ it holds that $P\leq N_G(P)$, or not?

If this is true, to use it in this case we have to know if $N_G(P)$ is a Sylow subgroup of $G$, or not?

Comment: Any subgroup $H$ of $G$ is always contained in $N_G(H)$.  In fact, $N_G(H)$ is the largest subgroup of $G$ of which $H$ is a normal subgroup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have that $\;P\le N_G(p)\le N_G(N_G(P))\;$ , so:

$$x\in N_G(N_G(P))\implies P^x\le (N_G(P))^x=N_G(P)$$

But all Sylow $\;p-$subgroups of one given group are conjugated in that group, so since we got $\;P, P^x\le N_G(P)\;$ , there exists $\;y\in N_G(P)\;$ such that

$$P^y=P^x\implies P^{xy^{-1}}=P\implies xy^{-1}\in N_G(P)\implies x\in N_G(P)$$

and we've finished.

Comment: From the fact that $x\in N_G(N_G(P))$ we have that $(N_G(P))^x=N_G(P)$, right? Why do we have that $P^x\leq (N_G(P))^x$ ?

Comment: @MaryStar Because $\;P\le N_G(P)\;$ .  For any set $\;S\subset N_G(P)\;$ we'd have $\;S^x\subset N_G(P)^x\;$

Comment: We have that $P, P^x\leq N_G(P)$. We have that $P$ is a $p$-Sylow subgroup of $G$, how do we conclude that it is also a $p$-Sylow subgroup of $N_G(P)$ ? Also how do we conclude that $P^x$ is a $p$-Sylow subgroup of $N_G(P)$ ?

Comment: @MaryStar $\;P\;$ is characterized by having order the greatest power of a prime $\;p\;$ that divides the whole group $\;G\;$. If it is contained in some subgroup then this obviously continues to be true...I really don't understand what isn't clear here.

Comment: I got it!! Thank you very much!! :-)

Answer (score 3):

Some facts you may be able to put together:

-If $K$ is any subgroup of $G$ containing $P$, then $P$ is also a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $K$.  Any other Sylow $p$-subgroup of $K$ is of the form $kPk^{-1}$ for some $k \in K$.

-$P$ is normal in $K$ if and only if $P$ is the only Sylow $p$-subgroup of $K$.

-If $H$ is a subgroup of a group $M$, then $H$ is normal in $M$ if and only if $N_M(H) = M$.

-You always have $N_G(P) \subseteq N_G(N_G(P))$.  To show that they are equal, it is enough to show that $P$ is the only Sylow $p$-subgroup of $N_G(N_G(P))$.

Comment: We have that $$P\leq N_G(P)\leq G\tag 1$$ right? For the last point, where you say that we always have that $N_G(P) \subseteq N_G(N_G(P))$, do we set at the relation $(1)$ : $P=N_G(P)$ ? If we do that, why can we do that? Is $N_G(P)$ also a $p$-Sylow subgroup?

Comment: Third fact looks backwards perhaps you mean $M\leq H$?

Comment: You're right, I've made a mistake.  Give me a few minutes to edit my post and get it right

Comment: @Mary Star, yes $P \subseteq N_G(P) \subseteq G$.  We never assume that $P = N_G(P)$.  In general, $N_G(P)$ is larger than $P$, so you can't expect it to be a Sylow $p$ subgroup.

Comment: Ah ok... Why is it enough to show that $P$ is the only $p$-Sylow subgroup of $N_G(N_G(P))$ ? I got stuck right now...

Comment: Because, then $P$ will be a normal subgroup of $N_G(N_G(P))$.  That shows that $N_G(N_G(P))$ is contained in the normalizer of $P$ in $G$.

Comment: Ah ok... Thanks a lot!! :-)